# Reading next line InputStream Java

Tags: java, newline, break

I have an InputStream that would read from a text file. I noticed that the input stream doesn't read from a blank next line.

Sample text file:

```
[This is

A test file

Here.]
```

The code:

```
while ((str = br.readLine())!= null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Some text files would have multiple break lines in between. How do I get the input stream to accept break lines ?

As can be seen from the sample text file, '[This is' is followed by an empty line and then followed subsequently by 'A test file'. How do I read the empty line in between the two sets of strings ? (That is my definition of line break / break line)

Comment: What do you mean by a "break line"?  You mean a line containing only \r\n or \n (depending on the OS)?

Comment: BufferedReader doesn't skip blank lines--I wonder if what you're seeing as two blank lines could really be CR LF?

Comment: Yeah, I suggest using a BufferedReader too, I have never had problems with that skipping blank lines.

Comment: [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) does not have a readLine() method. Could you please post all your code? What are you expecting to read on an empty line?

Comment: Agreed with @Ishtar: InputStream's deal with bytes not characters -- as such there is no concept of "lines" since there is no concept of characters and as such no concept of '\r'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
while ((str = br.readLine())!= null && str.trim().length()>0) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

This gives you all the non blank lines.

Comment: Not super sure here but I'd guess this only gives the first lines until an empty line is read. Plus, it should be !str.trim().isEmpty().

Comment: isEmpty() is fine if you have Java 6+.

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader will read all the lines in the file regardless of whether they're blank or not.  It will look for line breaks: LF+CR on Windows and LF on GNU/Linux.  According to the BufferedReader documentation:

> A line is considered to be terminated
>   by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a
>   carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage
>   return followed immediately by a
>   linefeed.

So, it depends on what your text file really looks like.  Does it really have carriage-returns and line-feeds between the lines or is it just displaying that way?  You can find this out by looking at the file in a Hex editor (LF is 0x0A and CR is 0x0D).  If so, then BufferedReader should be giving you those blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the mistake, it's a BufferedReader taking in a InputStream. The BufferedReader did read every line including the next line / break line / line break. The problem was with my algorithm I wrote that simply missed the next line / break line / line break. Sorry for the hassle and trouble.

Thanks for all the answers.